# Pedir como parametro un objeto de Polimorfismo

Tags: java

Hola tengo un error y es que cuando pido por parametro un objeto **Cliente** yo le paso un objeto tipo **Persona** con comportamiento de Cliente,
osea que creo polimorfismo asi:

`Persona cliente = new Cliente(nombre,num_cuenta,cedula);`

Cuando le paso el objeto cliente a mis metodos:

```
Transacciones transaccion = new Transacciones();
    Persona cliente = new Cliente("Junner",1,"1312790932");
    transaccion.agregarDinero(cliente, 50.00);
    transaccion.mostrarDinero(cliente);
    transaccion.retirarDinero(cliente, 25.00);
    transaccion.mostrarDinero(cliente);
```

me manda un error de incompatibilidad ahi en cliente y lo entiendo por que me pide un objeto **Cliente**  y no **Persona**

```
public class Transacciones implements Abono, Retiro {

@Override
public void agregarDinero(Cliente cliente, Double cantidad) {
    Double result = cliente.getSaldo_actual() + cantidad;
    cliente.setSaldo_actual(result);
}

@Override
public void retirarDinero(Cliente cliente, Double cantidad) {
    Double result = cliente.getSaldo_actual() - cantidad;
    cliente.setSaldo_actual(result);
}

public void mostrarDinero(Cliente cliente) {
    System.out.println("Su saldo actual es : " + cliente.getSaldo_actual());

}
```

}

Pero me pregunto si habra una manera de pedir por parametro un objeto polimorfeado de tipo **Persona** con comportamiento de **Cliente**

Comment: ¿Por qué tu variable `cliente` es de tipo `Persona` y no de tipo `Cliente`?

Comment: Pues por que es un ejercicio para aplicar polimorfismo, esa es la idea, por que claro puedo hacerla tipo Cliente y fin del problema, pero ya no estaria usando polimorfismo ):

Comment: Si es un ejercicio de Polimorfismo, entonces vas en la vía contraria. Sugeriría hacerlo de otra manera. Por ejemplo, puedes especializar un par de clases que hereden de  `Cliente`, por ej: `ClienteCorporativo`, `ClientePersonal` y pasar estos a los métodos que esperan clientes. O bien pasar el cliente a un método que espere personas. De hecho, en la declaración y asignación:  `Persona cliente = new Cliente()` ya estás utilizando polimorfismo, pues le asignas una instancia de `Cliente` a una variable de tipo `Persona`, pero en la llamada tal como la intentas hacer, no habría polimorfismo.

Comment: Buena idea la de heredar de Cliente, osea si sabia que estaba usando pero me molestaba la idea que el tipo de dato en el parametro sea Persona y no Cliente, por que se supone que solo los clientes pueden hacer transacciones.

Comment: En `Transaccion`, lo correcto es dejar el parámetro de tipo `Cliente`. Si re-lees mi comentario, verás que mi sugerencia no es cambiar los tipos en estos métodos.

Comment: Claro ahi nomas dejaria el tipo de dato Cliente en el parametro. si te entiendo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definición rápida de polimorfismo:**
Se puede recibir un objeto de la subclase donde se espere un objeto de la super clase

> Pero me pregunto si habrá una manera de pedir por parámetro un objeto
>   polimorfeado de tipo Persona con comportamiento de Cliente

Para hacer eso entonces Cliente debe heredar de Persona en la herencia de clases que tengas en tu código.

Seria algo así como esto:

```
class Persona{
  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;
}

class Cliente extends Persona{
   private float cuenta;
}
```

Ahora en donde requieras un valor de la super clase (Persona) podras usar un valor de la sub clase (Cliente), en donde sea que requieras un valor de tipo Persona en este caso, entonces Cliente se ajustara y se refundira por asi decirlo y podra comportarse como un Persona.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Sistema{
  public static void main(){
    ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList();
    personas.add(new Cliente());
  }
}
```

Comment: Si te entendo, pero se esta raro que la persona herede del Cliente y no lo queria dejar asi osea por que se ve mas coherente que el Cliente herede de Persona

Comment: Si, entonces seria a la inversa, Cliente debería heredar de Persona y esperarías un objeto de tipo  Persona donde quieres que el polimorfismo ocurra

Comment: Gracias bro supongo que toca hacer eso!